# How to add custom permission for a role in liferay 6.2 ga3

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

i want to add a new role on which i need to assign new set of permission (custom permissions).trying to do this in liferay 6.2 ga3 with tomcat and mysql as DB.
Eg: the new role will be ticket admin and the new permission i want to assign to him is "book ticket".

Comment: What did you try so far and with which result? Just asking for the documentation is off topic for SO

Comment: @OlafKock i got one solution with using custom fields.using custom fields for the role entity and another way i found was adding a portlet with custom permissions with resource action configuration and on the define permission page we can select that from applications section

Comment: @gokul you can post your findings as answer it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a new role in Administration you can create a hook to override custom creation Roles and add your new ones.

Also you can create your roles and provide custom fields for them, managing you own permissions in your portlets (this is a really flexible way to do it when it has a deep logic) retrieving that customfields with expandoBridge mechanism.